# How do I catch a SqlException thrown by RAISERROR called in a trigger set off by Entity Framework 4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, triggers

I have Entity Framework set up to update a table.  The update is intercepted by an instead-of trigger, which calls RAISERROR:

```
CREATE TRIGGER mySchema.UpdateBusinessObjects
ON mySchema.BusinessObjects
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
    RAISERROR(''test error from SQL'',16,1)
    RETURN
```

In my repository class, I'm attempting to catch the SqlException generated by the RAISERROR in SQL:

```
public void SaveBusinessObject(BusinessObject b) {
    try {
         repo.Entry(b).State = EntityState.Modified;
         repo.SaveChanges();
    } catch (SqlException ex) {
         // handle exception here
    }
}
```

The problem is that C# isn't catching the SqlException; it gets passed up to the caller as an unhandled exception ("SqlException was unhandled by user: test error from SQL").  What?!

It looks like EF's SaveChanges() somehow is passing the exception up over my try catch block.  I have tried switching my catch statement to catch (Exception ex) in case the EF exception is somehow more general, but I still get an unhandled SqlException.  Am I missing something simple here?  What's the problem with the SaveChanges() method?

Comment: Try with an empty catch just to see what happens

Comment: It seems in this situation that 2 exceptions are shown when in debugging mode in Visual Studio: the first is a "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException" that is not caught by *any* "catch()" type statement.  The second is a "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" that is caught by .NET, and contains the former as the InnerException.  However, only the latter causes .NET to crash - the first is ignored.  Could it be that the former is coming from an outside process, like SQL server?

Answer (score 1):

I tried almost the exact same trigger you have on a table and tried to save the corresponding (new) object through the entity framework. From what i can see, the exception being thrown is of the type System.Data.UpdateException and not SqlException. The inner exception is SqlException and does contain the custom message that you have raised in the trigger that is 'test error from SQL'. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.. the problem is that I can't catch the exception even with the most basic exception type, so I'm unable to dig in and figure out what type it is.  What do you mean "from what you can see"?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things :-

1. If you want RAISERROR to throw a SqlException, you need to set its severity above 10. Errors with a severity of 10 and below are informational, and thus don't throw exceptions.
2. Catch EntityException
   or Set a breakpoint in the general Exception's catch block. In the Immediate Window, inspect the type of the exception: ex.GetType();

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to have an exception avoiding one try catch is having the exception in a different thread. Could the EF code be executed on a different thread? Maybe you can enable exception throwing on 1º chance at the Exceptions dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem.

I was using MVC mini profiler to profile query times. I found that if I removed it from my project, then the exceptions were caught as I expected.